# How to configure electron with vuejs and tailwindcss

Tags: vue.js, electron, tailwind-css

I have not been able to configure a project from scratch with these technologies.
Or if I can use nuxtjs with electronjs

[electronjs](https://electronjs.org/)

[vuejs](https://vuejs.org/)

[tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its best to use a template starter such as this one:

```
https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/vue-electron
```

and then configure tailwindcss following the guide here:

```
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/
```

I hope that helps