# Creating an Electron app with Vuejs, Webpack and tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, electron, tailwind-css

I try to get an Electron app running with [webpack](http://webpack.js.org), [Vuejs](http://vuejs.org) and [tailwindcss](http://tailwindcss.com), starting with the [electron-webpack](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack) template package and adding Vuejs and tailwindcss afterwards, but tailwindcss doesn't work.

There is this [equivalent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061911/how-to-configure-electron-with-vuejs-and-tailwindcss) on SO, but the solution mentioned there uses [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue), which has over 200 open issues and doesn't seems to be maintained anymore.

Does anybody has an idea what went wrong here? I proceeded as follows:

1. Initialize Electron webback boilerplate (according to [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack-quick-start)):

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack-quick-start.git project
   cd project
   rm -rf .git
   ```
2. Install Vuejs:

   ```
   yarn add --dev vue css-loader vue-loader vue-template-compiler
   ```
3. Setting up webpack for Vuejs:

   ```
   const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

   module.exports = {
       module: {
           rules: [
               {
                   test: /\.vue$/,
                   use: 'vue-loader'
               }
           ],
           plugins: [
               new VueLoaderPlugin()
           ]
       }
   }
   ```
4. Test Vuejs by modifying `src/renderer/index.js` to:

   ```
   'use strict';
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import App from './App.vue'

   new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       render(h) {
           return h(App)
       }
   })
   ```

   and adding `src/renderer/App.vue`:

   ```
   <template>
       <div>Welcome</div>
   </template>
   ```

   → Works so far.
5. Install tailwindcss:

   ```
   yarn add —-dev tailwindcss postcss-loader autoprefixer
   ```
6. Add tailwindcss to project:

   - `src/renderer/index.js`:

     ```
     ...
     import './assets/styles.css';
     ...
     ```
   - `src/assets/styles.css`:

     ```
     @tailwind base;
     @tailwind components;
     @tailwind utilities;
     ```
7. Include postcss-loader to webpack:

   - Add `postcss.config.js`:

     ```
     const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
     const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

     module.exports = {
       plugins: [
         tailwindcss,
         autoprefixer,
       ],
     };
     ```
   - Modify `webpack.config.js`:

     ```
     ...
     module.exports = {
         module: {
             rules: [
                 ...,
                 {
                     test: /\.css$/,
                     use: [
                     'vue-style-loader',
                     { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                     'postcss-loader'
                     ]
                 }
         ...
     ```
8. Test tailwindcss by modifying `App.vue`:

   ```
   <template>
       <div class="bg-blue-100">Welcome</div>
   </template>
   ```

   → Failed: Background of "Welcome" text should be blue, but isn't, text is still serif.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Outdated packages/plugins/repos are mostly developer's dilemma. There could be other choices out there that is being maintained regularly, but what if we can’t find something to meet our needs…  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Anyway, I recommend using **Vue-CLI** instead, and use vue plugins along the way, such as electron and tailwind.

1. [Vue-CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) uses webpack [under the hood](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html), by adding/configuring your `vue.config.js`. You can go ahead and install it: `yarn global add @vue/cli`.
2. Create a project with vue-cli: `vue create myproject`. Then

```
cd myproject
yarn install
```

3. Add [Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/) plugin, that will build your VueJS app as a desktop app. Install with `vue add electron-builder`. Choose electron version. And test run with `yarn electron:serve`.
4. Thereafter, you can add the [tailwindcss plugin](https://github.com/forsartis/vue-cli-plugin-tailwind) via `vue add tailwind`. Along the installation, you’ll be prompted with the tailwind config generation, choose `full` so you can test everything after, then customize later.

Following all their installation process, and leave all the defaults as is, try to test if the tailwindcss is working:

```html
/* in App.vue */

<template>
  <div id="app" class="flex p-5">Test</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
}
</script>

<style>
body, html {
  @apply bg-white;
}
</style>
```

finally with: `yarn electron:serve`

Comment: Wow, worked instantly. Using the vue-cli seems to be very straightforward, that's awesome.